# Correlations in classical-quantum states

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-information

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces with $\mathrm{dim}(X)=n$ and $\mathrm{dim}(Y)=m$. Let $\rho$ be a density operator on $X \otimes Y$ such that the reduced density operator on $X$ is a classical state; that is,
$\mathrm{Tr}_{Y}(\rho) = \sum_{i=1}^n p(i) u_i u_i^*$, where $\{u_i\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $X$, $\sum_{i=1}^n p(i) = 1$, $p(i) \geq 0$ for all $i$, and $u_i^*$ is complex conjugate of $u_i$.

How can we prove that the compound state $\rho$ is always of the following form:
$\rho = \sum_{i=1}^n p(i) u_i u_i^* \otimes \sigma_i$, where $\sigma_i$ is an arbitrary density operator on $Y$ for all $i$?

Comment: The statement you are trying to prove is wrong. Consider for example the maximally entangled state $\rho=uu^*$, where $u=(e_1\otimes e_1+\cdots+e_n\otimes e_n)/\sqrt{n}$ and $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $X=Y$. Then  $\rho$ is not quantum-classical, but it's reduced density operator is $\operatorname{Tr}_Y(\rho) =\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} e_ie_i^*$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I saw this statement in "The Theory of Quantum Information" by J. Watrous at pages 95-96. Probably, the book is stating something else.

Comment: An *ensemble* of quantum states is essentially a probability distribution $\{p_1,\dots,p_n\}$ along with a collection of density operators $\{\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_n\}$. The book is essentially stating that any ensemble can be associated with the corresponding state $\sum_{i=1}^np_i\, E_{i,i}\otimes\sigma_i$.

Comment: Note, however, that an ensemble is distinct from the state $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i \sigma_i$ that is the result from mixing that ensemble.

Comment: @luftbahnfahrer what is the difference between "an ensemble" and the corresponding mixture here?

Comment: There are infinitely many ensembles that yield the same mixed state. However, ensembles are in one-to-one correspondence with classical-quantum states of the form $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i\, E_{i,i} \otimes \sigma_i$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Instead of the above statement, can we prove the following: Let $\Delta$ be a completely dephasing channel on $X$ and let $\rho$ be a density operator on $X \otimes Y$ such that $\Delta \otimes I(\rho) = \rho$ and $\mathrm{Tr}_{Y}(\rho) = \sum_{i=1}^n p(i) u_i u_i^*$, where $I$ is an identity channel on $Y$. Then, the compound state $\rho$ is always of the following form:
$\rho = \sum_{i=1}^n p(i) u_i u_i^* \otimes \sigma_i$, where $\sigma_i$ is an arbitrary density operator on $Y$ for all $i$.